# Combine many regression coefficients into one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I have multiple regression lines. I want to combine the coefficients into one dataframe for easy visualization.

However, not all regressions have the same coefficients, so I was not able to use a for loop looking for the coefficient name.

Here is an example with same sample data and the desired output.

```
df=structure(list(x1 = c(-0.689814979498939, -0.509885025360363, 
-0.20248689168896, -1.79535329549682, 1.60447678701814, -0.408696703105769, 
0.97243696942363, -0.688339413750959, -0.359380427396309, 1.11638856659614
), x2 = c(0.775426469430265, 0.367906637531888, 0.965721516497862, 
-0.601113535090469, -0.655567870650469, 1.45494263752806, 0.187276141272287, 
-0.659949502938592, -0.481763339717836, -0.581132345668067), 
    x3 = c(-0.17202393327554, 0.022376822081548, -1.05069599269781, 
    -0.631926480864125, 1.76178640615702, -1.60488439781703, 
    0.172936842119056, 0.750091896988, -1.60900096983098, 0.443223570706679
    ), x4 = c(-0.117822668731567, -0.645150368596604, -1.58642572549226, 
    0.3630617077837, -1.00866095836508, 0.696818785571135, 0.978471598076335, 
    -0.315392158997475, 1.37594860146428, 0.0574562910914235), 
    y = c(-1.07067139899979, -0.360297366336307, 0.0328023505398295, 
    1.07908579247402, 0.185603676169661, 0.384858869675533, 0.62179479088495, 
    1.44265090318836, 0.340526158232088, -1.20387054108186)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

model1=lm(y~x1, data=df)
model2=lm(y~x2, data=df)
model3=lm(y~x2+x4, data=df)
model4=lm(y~x2+x3+x4, data=df)

coefs_x1=c(-0.2749230,NA,NA,NA)
coefs_x2=c(NA,-0.2795309,-0.2599686,-0.40977455)
coefs_x3=c(NA,NA,NA,-0.18740855)
coefs_x4=c(NA,NA,0.1568399,0.04981574)

output_df=data.frame(coefs_x1,coefs_x2,coefs_x3,coefs_x4)
> output_df
   coefs_x1   coefs_x2   coefs_x3   coefs_x4
1 -0.274923         NA         NA         NA
2        NA -0.2795309         NA         NA
3        NA -0.2599686         NA 0.15683990
4        NA -0.4097746 -0.1874086 0.04981574
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

forms <- list(x1 = y~ x1, x2 = y ~ x2, x3 = y ~ x2 + x4, x4 = y ~ x2 + x3 + x4)


map_df(forms, ~coef(lm(.x, data = df))) %>%
     select(-1) 

# A tibble: 4 x 4
      x1     x2      x4     x3
   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 -0.275 NA     NA      NA    
2 NA     -0.280 NA      NA    
3 NA     -0.260  0.157  NA    
4 NA     -0.410  0.0498 -0.187
```

Another option:

```
map(forms, ~t(coef(lm(.x, data = df)))) %>%
  plyr::rbind.fill.matrix() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(-1)

         x1         x2         x4         x3
1 -0.274923         NA         NA         NA
2        NA -0.2795309         NA         NA
3        NA -0.2599686 0.15683990         NA
4        NA -0.4097745 0.04981574 -0.1874086
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, here is what I would typically do using `dplyr`.

You can call directly each of the coefficients. They are "inside" the objects named "model." Once you call `model1$coeffcients` it will return you the coefficients, including the intercept. Since you don't want the intercept (at least you didn't mention it in your question), I'm removing it using `baseR` with the `[-1]` argument, that removes the first column.

Then I'm putting all the lines together with `bind_rows()` and organize the presentation with `select()`. The function `bind_rows()` will merge each row, and add the new columns also adding `NA`, for missings. Which solves your problem.

### Solution

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(model1$coefficients[-1],
          model2$coefficients[-1],
          model3$coefficients[-1],
          model4$coefficients[-1]) %>% 
  select(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      x1     x2     x3      x4
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 -0.275 NA     NA     NA     
2 NA     -0.280 NA     NA     
3 NA     -0.260 NA      0.157 
4 NA     -0.410 -0.187  0.0498
```

FYI, the output is the same as yours, but `tibble`s usually round it for presentation, but in the background, it has all the decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base` R (list created simply to make it easier to make names, original idea was to `rbind` with `do.call`)

```
# assumes coefs will be named coefs_x+
coefs <- ls(pattern="coefs_x*")
as.data.frame(coefs, col.names=paste0("coefs_x",1:length(coefs )))

   coefs_x1   coefs_x2   coefs_x3   coefs_x4
1 -0.274923         NA         NA         NA
2        NA -0.2795309         NA         NA
3        NA -0.2599686         NA 0.15683990
4        NA -0.4097746 -0.1874086 0.04981574
```

Comment: This takes into assumption that OP has extracted the coefs and added the necessary missing NA's. This is exactly what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Not really, my first answer had manually typed coefs but I'm lazy and since in OP's data example they manually create the `coef` vectors, then these can be extracted from the `.GlobalEnv`. OP states "However, not all regressions have the same coefficients, so I was not able to use a for loop looking for the coefficient name"

Comment: And thats where the issue lies. if OP had the coefficients with the NA's appended in the correct missing possitions, they could directly create the dataframe. But they are trying to create the dataframe with existing models. The last two steps are to show what OP needs.